# keyBinding doesn't works until a button is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, key-bindings

A usercontrol should get added every time when the shortcut is clicked. But when i close the usercontrol and try to open it again the shortcut doesn't work. The focus is somewhere else.when some button is clicked on the window and shortcut is clicked usercontrol is added.

UserControl 1:

```
<Window
    x:class="Class1"
    ...>    
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="ButtonCLickCommand "
                    Modifiers="Control" Key="Q"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <Grid x:Name="Grid">
        <Button Content = "OpenUserControl" Command="ButtonCLickCommand "/>
        <Button Content = "Temp"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CodeBehind:

```
public ICommand ProfileCommand { get; set; }
ProfileCommand = new RelayCommand(Button_Click());

public void Button_Click()
{            
     _control = new Class2();
     _control.CloseAction = CloseClass2;
     Panel.SetZIndex(_control, 10);
     _control.Width = 200;
     _control.Height = 200;
     Grid.Children.Add(_control);
}
public void CloseClass2(Class2 control)
{
     Grid.Children.Remove(control);            
}
```

UserControl 2:

```
<UserControl
    x:class="Class2"
    ...>    
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="x" Click="Button_Click" Height="30">
        <Rectangle Fill="Black" Height="70"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Code Behind:

```
namespace namespace1.UserControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ProfileUserControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Class2 : UserControl
    {
        public Action<Class2> CloseAction;

        public Class2()
        {           
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CloseAction(this);
        }
    }
}
```

This is outline of My code. Help me i'm new to WPF.
Thanks for every answer i get. :)

Comment: How are you attaching an event handler to the Command property? Doesnt it give an error?

Comment: sorry i just gave the outline of the code. I am following MVVM i don't want to add the view model code. Now i have added it

Answer (score 0):

In Your KeyBinding ... you should bind to your command in View model
....
to make it easier .. it omit the view model ... here is the solution,note that i made some tweaks for simplicity:

in mainWindow.xaml :

```
 <Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding ButtonClickCommand,RelativeSource{RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}" Modifiers="Control" Key="Q"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>

    <StackPanel x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Button Content = "OpenUserControl" Command="{Binding ButtonClickCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

and here is the code behind:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
    public RelayCommand ButtonClickCommand { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    ButtonClickCommand= new RelayCommand(MyButtonClickExcute);
    }
    private void MyButtonClickExcute()
    {
    UserControl1 userControl1 = new UserControl1 {Width = 50, Height = 50,CloseAction = RemoveUserControlFromPanel };
    Panel.SetZIndex(userControl1, 10);
    MainGrid.Children.Add(userControl1);
    }
    public void RemoveUserControlFromPanel(UserControl1 userControl1)
    {
    MainGrid.Children.Remove(userControl1);
    }
    }
```

and for userControl.xaml:

```
<Grid>
<Border Background="Blue" CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="15" BorderBrush="Green">
                <Button VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="125" Height="75" Content="Close" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"></Button>
</Border>
</Grid>
```

finally, code behind for userControl:

```
 public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public Action<UserControl1> CloseAction { get; set; }
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CloseAction(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: when the Usercontrol is closed the focus is not on the mainwindow. So the event(add new usercontrol)doesn't get called.To bring back the focus to mainwindow some other button is clicked only then the focus is back on mainwindow. How to change the focus ?.

Comment: i am not sure that i understand you completely ...
main window still active after removing user control from the panel 's children .. why could lose focus?
i uploaded the project so you can examine it to:
https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/829671/Wpf%20Test.rar